# Some question about ASGI / running Flask app with Hypercorn

Tags: python, flask, asynchronous

I would like to build an asynchronous API server with Flask and Hypercorn. I had run a unit test to send multiple requests concurrently for synchronous and asynchronous approaches, but the result was almost the same.

Here is the server side code with Hypercorn, I commented the asynchronous code:

```
from time import sleep
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
from hypercorn.config import Config
from hypercorn.asyncio import serve
import asyncio

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS (app)

async def process_request (index, data1, data2): # no async if synchronous
   from random import randint
   delay = randint(1,5)
   await asyncio.sleep(delay) # sleep(delay) if synchronous
   return f'findex}, {data1+data2}, delay={delay}'

@app.route('/test', methods= ['POST']) async def test ():
   try:
      index = request. form [' index']
      datal = request. form ['data1']
      data2 = request. form ['data2']
      result = await process_request (index, data1, data2) # no await if synchronous
      return jsonify(result)
   except Exception as e:
      print("Exception: ", e)
      return jsonify('Unexpected Exception')
if __name__== "__main__":
   asyncio.run(serve (app, Config()) , debug=True) # app.run(debug=True) if asynchronous
```

And here is the log:

1. run Flask app without Hypercorn:

```
Response Data:  2, HelloWorld, delay=1 ;Response time:  1
Response Data:  0, HelloWorld, delay=2 ;Response time:  2
Response Data:  1, HelloWorld, delay=3 ;Response time:  3
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 3.012s

OK
```

2. run Flask app with Hypercorn:

```
Response Data:  2, HelloWorld, delay=2 ;Response time:  2
Response Data:  1, HelloWorld, delay=3 ;Response time:  3
Response Data:  0, HelloWorld, delay=4 ;Response time:  4
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 4.011s

OK
```

Since the total response time of first test was match the last response time, seems like the origional Flask app handle request asynchronously, but it doesn't make sence at all. How come Flask app can concurrently handle request and response without Hypercorn or any other thrid-party library?